# GDB: "warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds"

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, gdb, warnings, pass-by-reference

I have a C/GDB coding question which is driving me nuts.  (Coding on a Linux box, using GCC as my compiler.)

I'm working on an assignment where I have to code a hardware cache, which basically means I need to work with a 2D array of structs I have typedef'ed as struct `cacheLine`.  Here's how I think about the array in the code:

```
 [*] [*] [*] [*]    ...so here...  numSet = 4            (columns)
 [*] [*] [*] [*]                   numLines = 12         (total)
 [*] [*] [*] [*]                   numLinesPerSet = 3    (rows)
```

So "numLines" is really the TOTAL number of `cacheLine` structs, not the number of rows in the array.  (I don't mean for this to be confusing, it has to do with the assignment nomenclature.)

Here's how I thought I should allocate and pass the array by reference:

```
void initCache(int numSets, int numLines, cacheLine* (*cache)[numLines], int numLinesPerSet){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<numSets; i++){
            for(j=0; j<numLinesPerSet; j++){
                    // Now allocate each struct one-by-one
                    cache[i][j] = (cacheLine*) malloc(sizeof(cacheLine));
                    if(cache[i][j] == NULL){
                            printf("Error: not enough memory to malloc() cache.\n");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
            }
    }
}

int main(){
    ...
    cacheLine* myCache[numSets][numLines];                  // declare
    initCache(numSets, numLines, myCache, numLinesPerSet);  // allocate
    ...
}
```

(Yes, there is a similar freeCache() function at the end which I'm omitting here.)

So far, everything compiles and runs fine.  When I step into initCache() with GDB, it looks okay:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe308) at c-sim.c:55
56              initCache(numSets, numLines, myCache, numLinesPerSet);
(gdb) step
initCache (numSets=4, numLines=12, cache=0x7fffffffdf28, numLinesPerSet=3) at c-sim2.h:122
122     void initCache(int numSets, int numLines, cacheLine* (*cache)[numLines], int numLinesPerSet){
(gdb)
```

So far, so good.  Here's where things go south for me.  Much later on in the code, I call another function, whose signature is very much like my initCache():

```
void cacheThisData(int numSets, int numLines, cacheLine* (*myCache)[numLines], int someData) {
    // do stuff with someData
}

int main(){
    ...
    cacheLine* myCache[numSets][numLines];                  // from
    initCache(numSets, numLines, myCache, numLinesPerSet);  // before...
    ...
    int someData;    //  holds data to-be-cached
    cacheThisData(numSets, numLines, myCache, someData);
    ...
}
```

Here's what happens when I step into the `cacheThisData()` fuction with GDB:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe308) at c-sim.c:105
105                                     cacheThisData(numSets, numLines, myCache, someData);
(gdb) step
cacheThisData(numSets=4, numLines=12, warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds 0..-72057594037927936
warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds 0..-72057594037927936
myCache=warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds 0..-72057594037927936
warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds 0..-72057594037927936
warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds 0..-72057594037927936
warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds 0..-72057594037927936
warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds 0..-72057594037927936
warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds 0..-72057594037927936
warning: Range for type <error type> has invalid bounds 0..-72057594037927936
0x7fffffffdf28, data=1234) at c-sim3.h:145
145     void cacheThisData(int numSets, int numLines, cacheLine* (*myCache)[numLines], int someData) {
(gdb)
```

What the heck???  The code still seems to run fine, but I'm worried that whatever problem GDB smells here will come back to haunt me.  Better to fix it now.

I've noticed that if I change the function signature of `cacheThisData()` to pass only the array, GDB doesn't mind:

```
void cacheThisData(int numSets, int numLines, cacheLine* (*myCache)[numLines]) {}

int main(){
    cacheThisData(numSets, numLines, myCache);   // GDB likes this
}
```

But the moment I add one extra argument anywhere in `cacheThisData()`'s signature, I get the above GDB warning, always the same.  It doesn't matter if I put the extra argument at the beginning, int the middle, or at the end of the arguments into `cacheThisData()` - GDB complains.

I don't know what to make of this.  GDB appears to be saying that I'm passing in the `myCache` array with incorrect dimensions???  But numSets and numLines do not change.  Nor do I realloc() or anything like that to change the array's size.  The array doesn't change size between the `initCache()` and `cacheThisData()` functions, not at least as far as I can tell.

Any advice?  Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks,
-Pete

Comment: Which GCC, GDB version do you use? How do you compile, call GDB?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this with exactly the minimal code you show us? That is by removing all `...`?

Comment: Sorry guys, my program is quite large.  I deliberately wanted to post a skeleton version to just get the basic idea across.  I see now this isn't a good post.

Answer (score 0):

I never found the source of this problem.  However, my code is able to handle fairly large data sets and hasn't busted yet, so that's something.  I'm going to chalk this up to a mystery of life... and move on.  Many thanks to all who paused to read this post.